# Why isn't this replacing with the whole string in radio button value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using .replaceWith() to change the value of a radio button using an array:

```
$("#choice1").replaceWith("<li id = 'choice1'>" + "<input type='radio' >name='choice' value="+allQuestions[currentTurn].possibleAnswers[0]+">"+allQuestions[currentTurn].>possibleAnswers[0] "</li>");
```

when I have a string (eg. "The Last Battle"), the first `+allQuestions[currentTurn].possibleAnswers[0]` is only returning the first word of the string, where the same code, the second time, is returning the whole string.

Could someone tell me why? And how to make it so they both return the entire string?

Thanks!

Comment: The `>` before `name` isn't in the actual code, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the attribute value if it contains spaces.

```
$("#choice1").replaceWith("<li id = 'choice1'>" + 
    "<input type='radio' name='choice' value='" +
    allQuestions[currentTurn].possibleAnswers[0] +
    "'>" +
    allQuestions[currentTurn].>possibleAnswers[0] "</li>");
```

Otherwise, your HTML will look like this:

```
<input type='radio' value=The Last Battle>
```

As you can see from that, the value is just `The`, while `Last` and `Battle` look like additional attributes (SO's syntax highlighting even makes that clear).